# Perl print interpretation

Tags: perl

I'm going through one of the legacy scripts in our env and found below perl command embedded into a shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
printf "%s %s\\n", (stat($ARGV[1]))[9], $ARGV[0];
```

I have no knowledge of Perl.
Can someone help me understand what the author is trying to do here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The `stat` function returns status of the file given as argument, the 9th element is the last mmodify time.

This script prints the last modify time and the value provided in the first argument.

It's impossible to say more without knowing all the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

It prints the file's modification time (in Unix seconds).

The `@ARGV` array contains all command-line arguments, where `$ARGV[0]` is the first one, `$ARGV[1]` is second, and so on. (Note difference from e.g. C or Python, where item 0 is the script's own name.)

`stat($filename)` returns a list containing all fields that you would expect from the C stat() function. Its 9th element is the file's modification time. (See `perldoc -f stat`.)

So `(stat($ARGV[1]))[9]` gets you the mtime of the file specified as the script's second parameter. (The extra parens are necessary to cope with Perl's syntax, which doesn't allow `func()[]` for some reason.)

`printf` works exactly like C printf() or Bash printf, and each `%s` is expanded to the corresponding parameter; so it prints the mtime in Unix seconds, space, and then the script's first parameter.

```
$ ./yourscript.pl Hello! myfile.txt
1565012664 Hello!

$ date -d @1565012664
Mon Aug  5 16:44:24 EEST 2019
```